# Recording data with AngularJS in two steps

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, local-storage

I'm trying to save a series of variables in a two-step way using AngularJS and LocalStorage.
In the first step, the data of several variables will be saved in the variable `recordlist` but not pushed into LocalStorage. 
In the second step, the user is supposed to trigger another function and to record the data of one last variable and then push all into LocalStorage.

So far the first step works OK, the data is saved in the variable (not in LocalStorage) and displayed in the view, and in the second step the `recordlist` is pushed into the JSON in LocalStorage, but a second one will be created to store the last variable, instead of updating the first one.

So long story short, my problem is that until now I've only been able to record the data in the JSON separately, like so:

```
[
  {
    "date":"2014 10 15",
    "time":"18.52",
    "car":"791",
    "driver":"Eric",
    "from":"Log",
    "destination":"Airport",
    "pax":"2"
  },
  {
    "arrival":"18.52"
  }
]
```

What I really need is for the second step to update the first recordlist, not to create a new one, like this:

```
[
  {
    "date":"2014 10 15",
    "time":"18.52",
    "car":"791",
    "driver":"Eric",
    "from":"Log",
    "destination":"Airport",
    "pax":"2",
    "arrival":"18.52"
  }
]
```

This is my code:

```
$scope.recordlist = extractRecordJSONFromLocalStorage();
$scope.addRecord = function () {
        $scope.recordlist.push(
            {
                date: $scope.dateJson, 
                time: $scope.time, 
                car: $scope.carList.code, 
                driver: $scope.driverList.name,
                from: $scope.locationList.place,
                destination: $scope.locationList2.place, 
                pax: $scope.paxList
            }
        );

    $scope.custom = $scope.custom === false ? true: false;
    $scope.carList = 0;
    $scope.driverList = 0;
    $scope.locationList = 0;
    $scope.locationList2 = 0;
};

$scope.insertRecord = function () {
    $scope.arrivaltime = moment().format("HH.mm");

    $scope.recordlist.push(
        {
            arrival: $scope.arrivaltime
        }
    );

    jsonToRecordLocalStorage($scope.recordlist);
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: don't use push, push is for array. Just save it as object.

Comment: @wayne care to expand on that? Newbie alert : )

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.recordlist = extractRecordJSONFromLocalStorage();
$scope.addRecord = function () {
        $scope.recordlist = {
                date: $scope.dateJson, 
                time: $scope.time, 
                car: $scope.carList.code, 
                driver: $scope.driverList.name,
                from: $scope.locationList.place,
                destination: $scope.locationList2.place, 
                pax: $scope.paxList
            };

    $scope.custom = $scope.custom === false ? true: false;
    $scope.carList = 0;
    $scope.driverList = 0;
    $scope.locationList = 0;
    $scope.locationList2 = 0;
};

$scope.insertRecord = function () {
    $scope.arrivaltime = moment().format("HH.mm");

    $scope.recordlist.arrival = $scope.arrivaltime;

    jsonToRecordLocalStorage($scope.recordlist);
}
```

Comment: You solution saves the data in the proper order, but without array, and it messes with my view. Obviously I'm missing something. But thanks for trying!!